# Use multiple setInterval (or setTimeOut) in node.js server

Tags: node.js, settimeout, setinterval

Could I use a setInterval (or setTimeout) in node.js for each connected client?. How node would manage this?. Would there be performance problems?. I want to run a function from time to time on each client, and I do not know how to do it without using setInterval.

Comment: In what regards is the user connected, as in, is the connection persistent or socket based? Is there anything unique about the function to be ran or is it something that could occur once globally?

Comment: I use websocket(module ws) for client-server communication. The function is for all clients. The problem is that if it drops the internet connection from a client, the server gets nothing. I have to do a poll every so often to check which customers have fallen.

Comment: If the client disconnects(websocket connection) or closes the browser, the server if it receives the event, but if it drops the internet connection then the server gets nothing

Comment: I think it's a very serious error that the module does not control this. So to solve the problem I have to do a poll to all clients